# Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile: Speeding up iOS Kotlin framework compilation (linkPodFrameworkIosArm64)

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

The biggest hurdle regarding Kotlin Multiplatform is the slow compilation times when it comes to compiling the Kotlin native code to platform-specific code, which is most significant during the iOS compilation.

Performing any small modification on the shared code, will result in recompiling the framework all over again, which makes sense, but it's just painfully slow, especially provided that my Mac is kind of outdated (Air 2017) so the specs make the matter all the more worse. I wonder if any of you guys have found workarounds to this.

For reference, these are the Gradle task that takes up 99% of the time:

```
linkPodDebugFrameworkIosX64
linkPodDebugFrameworkIosArm64
linkPodDebugFrameworkIosSimulatorArm64
linkPodDebugFrameworkIosFat
```

Comment: I personally stopped using third party libraries in KMP part - I create an interface, on iOS side implement an object with this interface, and this object uses any third parties. Then I pass it to KMP library. It adds some boilerplate, but saves much build time, and adds more flexibility to using swift only code, which is not available from ObjC, and you don't need to convert Swift code to Kotlin, which you usually have as sample or working

Comment: This must be addressed at some point... it takes 7 seconds to build the Android side, and over 90 seconds to build the same iOS... unaccepable!